# How to limit the size of a list in Python while still making it change

Tags: python, variables, random, import

I am currently setting up a lottery system for some friends and myself.
At the moment I have the system set up fine however I want the system to stop adding numbers to the list and start checking the numbers against the predetermined ones I have set up.
So far I have had no luck I am hoping someone could help. If needed I can copy and paste my code here for you to view.
Thanks

```
import random
winning_numbers = [1,45,7,2,6]
user_numbers=[]
while user_numbers != winning_numbers:
  user_numbers = user_numbers[:1]
  user_numbers.append(random.randrange(1, 50))
  print(user_numbers)
else:
    print("Winner!")
    print(len(user_numbers))
if user_numbers > [5]:
    print("quit")
    exit()
```

Comment: Please post some code too

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and this: [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add numbers in array while array length user_numbers is less than winning_numbers. And then check if arrays are equals.

```
import random

winning_numbers = [1, 45, 7, 2, 6]
user_numbers = []
count_lose_combination = 0

while user_numbers != winning_numbers:
    while len(user_numbers) < len(winning_numbers):
        user_numbers.append(random.randrange(1, 50))
        print(user_numbers)

    if user_numbers == winning_numbers:
        print("lose count " + str(count_lose_combination))
    else:
        user_numbers = []
        count_lose_combination += 1
```

Comment: I'm hoping to automate this so i don't keep having to press CRTL+b I want to keep track of how many times the system will have to cycle through a random set of numbers until it matches up with the ones already set

Comment: @SeanMagennis i updated my code. You can use nested loop for this

Comment: thank you so so much, this has been such an education, i had to change the numbers between 1 and 10 becuase it was taking too long but it took 44000 tries to get there